# How to load all data on client

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net website with telerik controls. Im using multiple conditional grids (Show data based on selection in a grid.)
Every time I do new selection it is kinda slow (I'm using ajax call). Is it possible to preload all data to the client and then instantly show it to user.
I mean, is there any simple way of doing so?

Comment: So because loading data is slow you want to preload **all** data even if the user doesn't want to see it sometime? Why is lazy-loading data via asynchronous postbacks slow, how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that the slowness comes from the amount of data being rendered on your page.  Keep in mind that AJAX still goes through the entire life-cycle of the page; the savings come from not having to render the entire page, just the updated parts.

Are your AJAX settings correctly updating the controls, or do you have a massive 'pnlAllControls' updating 'pnlAllControls'?

For example -- if you have Grid1, Grid2, Grid3; and Grid1 updates (Grid2, Grid3) while Grid2 updates only (Grid3), you should set your AJAX accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are getting data from the server, it does not make sense to cache the data on the client. I am not sure how much control you have over configuring them [controls].

You can store/cache data on server side instead (e.g. Cache, Session etc.). The data retrieval from there should be fast unless you send tons of data back and forth. But, caching data (on either client or server) should only be considered if the amount is 1)predictable and 2)relatively small.

Another technique to consider is paging/sorting on the server side. From my experience, you can get a real performance boost using just this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to your question. It all depends on data volume, security requirements. Moreover, your controls may not be able to pull data from the client-side.